# Doctype changes height of table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I needed to add doctype strict otherwise IE doesn't work properly, it changes the height of td and tr tags. I tried doing several things suggested here but I think I missed something when reading since I'm really tired. Tried the w3.org validator no problems reported. Would really appreciate if you could point what I did wrong and give me some good site to see the right way of coding CSS and not the quirky way, here's the site http://pvpgn.freeiz.com/lagabuse/stats.php
and CSS
http://pvpgn.freeiz.com/lagabuse/stats.css

Comment: What do you want? What is happening?

Comment: I want to change the height of whole table or td/tr tags since it should fit the screen,it works if i delete the doctype but i need doctype if i want to display it in MSIE

Comment: Can you do this? Create a link which has the `doctype` and another without it. So that we can compare. :)

Comment: Here is the link http://pvpgn.freeiz.com/lagabuse/stats2.php

Comment: So you want like `stats2` or `stats`?

Comment: I want like stats2 but with doctype

Comment: Can you change the `doctype` to any other than `HTML 4.01`? Say XHTML?

Comment: Added it to stats.php,no change.

Comment: Really nice one. Gimme some time, lemme check. :)

Comment: Dude, got it. Lemme answer it! :)

Comment: Funny isn't it? We were seeing somewhere else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Add this in your `stat.css`:

```
p {margin: 0;}
```

Comment: Thank you,i was focusing on the div,table and tr tags that i forgot to check td ones :)

Comment: Same here. :) I was seeing `td` instead of `p`!

Answer (score -1):

```
.tr td, .tr2 td {
 font-size: 18px;
 height: 25px;}
```

Comment: Seriously, what are you trying to prove?